# Handle Simultaneous Client Request While Validating / issuing Jwt token

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jwt

I ran into an issue where i have exposed some api's for our mobile clients i.e android/ios ,when client calls certain api their request gets validated on the basis of jwt token we have provided while onboarding them into our system ,this jwt token contains an expiry duration of t time , now what happens when client hits two request simultaneously and t time has elapsed while checking/validation client request we found jwt is expired and we return a message with new jwt token to a client with extended expiry period also corresponding refresh token gets updated for the user in the database so that for furthur request we can authenticate a user on the basis that whether the user with this jwt is same that is inside this referesh token.

as per this process ,client's first request successfully proceeds and a new token is issued and returned to the client now what happens when the second request arrives and when we try to validate this jwt token with our refresh token which was updated by the client's first request returns an invalid authentication error to client.

i want to handle this scenario at our api level , something like dirty checking would help or not ?

i'm using spring boot spring data jpa

Comment: A JWT should be viewed, I think, as an independent passport of sorts.  There would be nothing wrong with a user being validated by two different JWT within a short timeframe, assuming that the claims pass for both, and the user account has not been suspended, etc.  So I'm not seeing a real problem here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tim but the problem is the algo written is such that it takes jwt and validates it on the basis of refresh token present in our database , now after the expiry period two same request with same jwt arrives,

Comment: here both should get Jwt expired and a new Jwt token in response but what is happening here that first request is process and jwt is validated and according  to the algorithm written it gets validated against referesh token in our database and refresh token is updated at that time only , now the 2nd request which was waiting in the queue to be processed gets validated which according to the algo is invalid as the refresh token in our database is changed by the first request by the same user , so while preforming the validation of jwt against refresh token invalidates the jwt provided